# How to tell geometrically/graphically the statistical properties of a ring distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, statistics, machine-learning, covariance

I pulled this distribution of a 2D random variable from page 5: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf

[image]

I want to know:

1. How can we infer the covariance matrix from the plot?
2. How can we infer the independence/dependence from the plot?

Similar to how this document breaks it down nicely for 2D gaussians: [http://www.cs.utah.edu/~tch/CS4640F2019/resources/A%20geometric%20interpretation%20of%20the%20covariance%20matrix.pdf](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Etch/CS4640F2019/resources/A%20geometric%20interpretation%20of%20the%20covariance%20matrix.pdf)

Comment: If it had been uniform random points on a circle radius $1$ then the variance of $x$ and of $y$ would have been $\frac12$, and their covariance $0$.  It is not quite that , so the variance is a little larger  (I think about $0.635$) but with the symmetry the covariance still about $0$.  You clearly do not have independence since knowing the value of $y$ gives you a big clue as to likely values of $x$

Comment: Is there an application you have in mind for this sort of 2D "ring" distribution?  A brief mention of it would improve your Question.